# IPTABLES chain restriction

Tags: networking, iptables

I have two network cards

```
eth0:- 172.16.91.70 (External Zone)
eth1:- 172.16.85.70 (Internal Zone)
```

I have clients in my Internal Zone which can access the external network. The ping goes fine and can access external net. Now I want to restrict the access for the internal zone. The external zone connects to another network that is 172.16.81.0 and that connects to 172.16.79.0

Now I want my internal zone be able to access complete 172.16.91.0 network, drop packets from 81.0 network and access 79.0 network. But I also don't want it to access internet because the squid proxy server is in 81.0 network.

Answer (score 1):

These will all appear in your FORWARD chain as you are acting as a router for those networks. Create the accept rules first, deny the rest later.

```
 iptables -I FORWARD -s 172.16.85.0/24 -d 172.16.91.0/24 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "allow to 172.16.91.0/24"
 iptables -I FORWARD -s 172.16.85.0/24 -d 172.16.79.0/24 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "allow to 172.16.79.0/24"
 iptables -I FORWARD -s 172.16.81.0/24 -d 172.16.85.0/24 -j DENY -m comment --comment "Nothing from 172.16.81.0/24"
```

I've followed your rules explicitly and not allowed to and from where mentioned, you *may* want to block both directions (but blocking traffic from a network means your sent packets are dropped on their return route through the firewall).